# Who manufactures BB droids?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, droids

As of the Last Jedi, we've seen the BB-series used by the First Order as well as the Resistance- what company makes them and isn't shy about selling to both sides?

Comment: Sphero?  ... sorry I’ll show myself out.

Comment: I'm (pretty) sure that we don't know. It's not confirmed in any of the supplementary materials that I've read, and I've read most everything that's available.

Comment: @Nu'Daq What evidence do you have that the BB series droids are sold directly by the manufacturing company to the Resistance and the First Order?  For all that we know the BB series robots have suddenly become popular because the patents expired and any Tom, Dick, or Harry manufacturing company is now legally free to make them?

Comment: @M.A.Golding Even if it did, there's still the question of who originally made them in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Industrial Automaton** is the manufacturer of BB units, among others. They have to no loyalty to either side in the various galactic conflicts, having manufactured astromechs used by both the Rebellion and the Empire, training remotes for the Jedi, and 2-1B surgical droids used by nearly every side for generations. This kind of plays into one of *The Last Jedi*'s themes, that war profiteers don't care about what side their commodities are used for, just that they are used. So, to reiterate, **Industrial Automaton** is the manufacturer of BB droids.

> Information courtesy of [*Star Wars*: Galaxy's Edge—*Droid Depot*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Droid_Depot) (it's canon)

Comment: Like the Ferengi say, war is good for business.

Comment: I suspected it might be these guys since they made the R-series too, but was waiting for confirmation or denial before I said anything.